# Viewing Long Documents on Projector Vertically

Tags: display, external-display, projector

Is there any such thing as being able to use a projector vertically so that you can view entire documents that are usually narrow in width and longer in length without having to scroll?

In our testing we were able to accomplish this by positioning the projector 90 degrees (vertically), probably a very bad idea as I'm sure they aren't designed for that. And then we had to turn the images sideways so that they would appear correctly on the projection. Of course, Windows still appeared sideways but the images at least looked correct. A better idea, if possible, would be to have the video output from the computer rotated but I'm not sure if that's possible.

I know that some Dell monitors allow you to rotate them for working on long documents. This is what we'd like to achieve only we need to be able to do it on a projector. I suppose we could use a large, widescreen TV but then we would need one that allows you to rotate it and display vertically. And I'm not sure if many of them have this capability. Maybe this has more to do with your graphics card than it does with the capabilities of the monitor.